# pygame set_timer() doesn't work inside a class

Tags: python, pygame

So apparently **pygame.time.set_timer()** doesn't work when used inside a class and I just can make it behave as a timer. Inside a class it will be called every frame

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Bird():
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 1
        
        self.count_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.count_timer, 1000)
    
    def go(self):
        if event.type == self.count_timer:
            print(self.count)
            self.count += 1

b = Bird()
   
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
  
    b.go()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

If the timer is outside of a class it works as expected and will be called once per second

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

count = 1
count_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(count_timer, 1000)
   
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
        if event.type == count_timer:
            print(count)
            count += 1

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Can anyone explain what needs to be done to make it work inside of a class? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `set_timer`. However, you have to call the `go` method in the event loop for each event:

```py
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        b.go()               # <--- INSTERT

    # b.go()                   <--- DELETE
```

I recommend passing the `event` object as an argument to the method:

```py
class Bird():
    # [...]
    
    def go(self, e):
        if e.type == self.count_timer:
            print(self.count)
            self.count += 1
```

```py
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        b.go(event)

    # [...]
```

Or pass the full list of events to the method:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Bird():
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 1
        self.count_timer = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.count_timer, 1000)
    
    def go(self, event_list):
        if self.count_timer in [e.type for e in event_list]:
            print(self.count)
            self.count += 1

b = Bird()
   
running = True
while running:
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False#
        
    b.go(event_list)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```